# Unwanted Javascript effect: Prototype is sharing closure between instances

Tags: javascript, closures, prototype

I'm making a game with timed levels. A level is 2 minutes long, and a countdown timer is displayed in the upper right corner. Mario style.

One way to keep track of the elapsed time would be to have my `Level` object have `elapsed` as a member variable.

```
Level.init = function(){
    this.elapsed = 0;  //member variable!
    return this;
};

Level.update = function(){
    this.countdown();
};

Level.countdown = function(){
    this.elapsed += 1;
    var remaining = (GAME_LENGTH*60) - (this.elapsed/TICKS);
    var minutes = Math.floor(remaining/60);
    var seconds = Math.floor(remaining%60);
    this.countdown.html(minutes + ":" + ("0"+seconds).slice(-2));       

    if (this.elapsed/TICKS >= GAME_LENGTH*60) {
        this.level_end();
    }
};
```

When the game engine needs a fresh level, it creates one in this way:

```
NewLevel = Object.create(Level).init();
```

However, I thought it might be nice to use a closure; `elapsed` is ONLY used by the `countdown` function, so it doesn't need to be a member variable of `Level`. `Level` doesn't need to know that `elapsed` exists.

```
//member variable this.elapsed has been removed
Level.init = function(){
    return this;
};

Level.update = function(){
    this.countdown();
};

//a closure is used to keep track of elapsed time
Level.countdown = (function(){
    var elapsed = 0;        
    return function() {
        elapsed += 1;
        var remaining = (GAME_LENGTH*60) - (elapsed/TICKS);
        var minutes = Math.floor(remaining/60);
        var seconds = Math.floor(remaining%60);
        this.countdown.html(minutes + ":" + ("0"+seconds).slice(-2));       

        if (elapsed/TICKS >= GAME_LENGTH*60) {
            elapsed = 0;
            this.end_level();
        }
    };
})();
```

But now I have a different problem. All copies of `Level` that are created share that `countdown` closure, because it is in the prototype chain. When a user quits the level early, and then starts a new level (trashing the old `Level` object instantiating a new `Level` object), the `elapsed` variable in the closure is not reset.

To say it in another way, the user quits the level early with 30 seconds left. Then the user starts the level again, but now, instead of a full 2 minutes, the countdown timer is still showing 30 seconds.

Is there an elegant way to fix this and still use a closure? Or must I revert to my previous solution, forget closures, and make `elapsed` a member variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an elegant way to fix this and still use a closure? Or must I revert to my previous solution, forget closures, and make elapsed a member variable?

It has to be instance-specific; that doesn't mean it has to be a property on the object. You can create the closure from within the `init` method:

```
//member variable this.elapsed has been removed
Level.init = function(){
    //a closure is used to keep track of elapsed time
    this.countdown = createCountdownMethod();
    return this;
};

Level.update = function(){
    this.countdown();
};

function createCountdownMethod(){
    var elapsed = 0;        
    return function() {
        elapsed += 1;
        var remaining = (GAME_LENGTH*60) - (elapsed/TICKS);
        var minutes = Math.floor(remaining/60);
        var seconds = Math.floor(remaining%60);
        this.countdown.html(minutes + ":" + ("0"+seconds).slice(-2));       

        if (elapsed/TICKS >= GAME_LENGTH*60) {
            elapsed = 0;
            this.end_level();
        }
    };
}
```

Or this may be a bit easier to read:

```
//member variable this.elapsed has been removed
Level.init = function(){
    var elapsed = 0;        

    //a closure is used to keep track of elapsed time
    Level.countdown = countdown;
    return this;

    function countdown() {
        elapsed += 1;
        var remaining = (GAME_LENGTH*60) - (elapsed/TICKS);
        var minutes = Math.floor(remaining/60);
        var seconds = Math.floor(remaining%60);
        this.countdown.html(minutes + ":" + ("0"+seconds).slice(-2));       

        if (elapsed/TICKS >= GAME_LENGTH*60) {
            elapsed = 0;
            this.end_level();
        }
    }
};

Level.update = function(){
    this.countdown();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move the definition of `countdown` into `init`, if you want to keep `elapsed` completely private to the `Level` instance.  That would look like:

```
//member variable this.elapsed has been removed
Level.init = function(){
    var elapsed = 0; // elapsed local to init
    this.countdown = function() {
        elapsed += 1;
        var remaining = (GAME_LENGTH*60) - (elapsed/TICKS);
        var minutes = Math.floor(remaining/60);
        var seconds = Math.floor(remaining%60);
        this.countdown.html(minutes + ":" + ("0"+seconds).slice(-2));       
        if (elapsed/TICKS >= GAME_LENGTH*60) {
            elapsed = 0;
            this.end_level();
        }
    };
    return this;
};

Level.update = function(){
    this.countdown();
};
```

It isn't possible to use a closure over a variable like `elapsed` for each instance without creating a new variable each time.